# removeGestureRecognizer method

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I've created a UIButton with multiple Gestures. Is there a way to remove ALL gesture Recognizers? Without the gesture recognizer object? I've looked at this method:

```
[myButton removeGestureRecognizer:(GestureRecongizer)];
```

However I don't have the Gesture recognizer object anymore. Is there a way to clean out my gestures without the recognizer object? Similiar to:

```
[myButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

this should do it

```
while (myButton.gestureRecognizers.count) {
    [myButton removeGestureRecognizer:[myButton.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the complete solution. If the button has more than one gesture recognizer, how will removing the recognizer at the index zero alone remove all of them?

Comment: well it's in a loop, and there will always be zero index present in the array. So it removes all the gestures.